# Cant upgrade linux kernel

Tags: kernel, dpkg, 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 and there is almost nothing I can do. If I want to install something via terminal, it will automatically try to update the kernel to  `linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic` and get stuck there.

Output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-56-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic is not installed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-56-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic
```

`apt autoremove` output ( stuck at 6%)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-56-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-43 linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-43-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 550 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 221817 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic_5.15.0-56.62_amd64.deb ...
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You have to reinstall the *2 not fully installed or removed* packages then, and only then, you can proceed normally.

Comment: I tried to install `linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic` but it got stuck :(

Comment: I am not getting any errors. It's stuck at 14%

Comment: you could try `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to 22.10. This will update to a newer kernel version.